# __MigrationHistory created again after applying second datacontext on same database

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database that I have been using and updating with Code First Migrations. I now want to add a second project that also uses the database with additional fields on some of the existing tables.

I assumed the best way to do this was to introduce a second datacontext with the second project.

As EF6 allows multiple DataContexts with additional ContextKey field, however enabling migrations and running with

PM> add-migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges

Causes another __MigrationHistory table to be created when there is already one there from the first project. I only need the row to be added InitialCreate.

I am not sure how I can suppress the generation of the __MigrationHistory table.

Wayne

Comment: You should just set the null initializer on the other context.

Comment: Do you mean Database.SetInitializer<othercontext>(null);